# Need help separating event driven code into layers that respect the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a View titled NewCalibrationView.xaml/.cs and it has a ViewModel NewCalibrationViewModel.cs

The xaml for the view:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <Label Content="Run Time:" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock Name="ClockTextBlock" Text="00:00:00:00" FontSize="16" Foreground="Red" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Label Content="Sample Count:" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="0" Name="SampleCountDigit" Foreground="Red" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

As one can see, I have a TextBlock that displays a stop-watch of sorts, and presently the code for running the stopwatch is in the code behind for the view (NewCalibrationView.cs)

```
public partial class NewCalibrationView: UserControl
{
    private DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
    private Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    private string _currentTime = string.Empty;
    private int _sampleCount = 0;

    public NewCalibrationView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    private void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stopWatch.IsRunning)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

            _currentTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);

            ClockTextBlock.Text = _currentTime;

            if (ts.Seconds%8 == 0)
            {
                _sampleCount++;
                SampleCountDigit.Text = _sampleCount.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClockTextBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
        stopWatch.Start();
        dt.Start();
    }
```

Because this code updates the view directly in the event handler (`dt.Tick();`) for the DispatchTimer's Tick event, I am having a hard time figuring out what to leave in the code-behind and what to put in the ViewModel.

Given the code-behind code I have shown here, what should go in the View and what should go in the ViewModel?

To start, I thought the StartButton_Click() should be transformed into a Command (which I generally put in the VM), but if that were the case then just doing that alone would mean that I would have to put the declaration of the DispatchTimer and StopWatch into the VM as well, which means that the rest of the code (event hander, its registration and so on) would have to be in the VM.

Does this sound right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were me, I'd move it all to the view model. I'd bind the `Text` properties of the 2 `TextBlock` to 2 strings on my view model. As you said, bind the `Button` command property to an `ICommand` on your viewmodel. Also, you could keep a Boolean property on your viewmodel that you bind to the color of your `TextBlock` (you'll need Data Triggers)

Comment: By Data Trigger you mean the xaml in UI responding to a flag such as a boolean when its true or false?

Comment: Yup...You'll just need a style for your `TextBlock` that you want to change the color of and that style will have the DataTrigger

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the insight and confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using an MVVM toolkit. I personally use and prefer the MVVM Light Toolkit, but there are other similar to it.

What I like about MVVM Light Toolkit is that its easy to use, simple and comes with great documentation and samples.

Once you established using MVVM, then bind your commands, text elements to your ViewModel. You can then handle your events in the ViewModel. Just think of your commands binding as an event.

I hope that helps. If you need more details let me know and I can respond.

Comment: I have heard of the toolkit before but have avoided using it for fear of a learning curve. I may use it having heard of it so many times. +1

Comment: Give it a try. You'll be up and running very quickly. That is what I love about it. Very simple to use and powerful if you use it to the full extent.